# Can terms of service and privacy policy URLs be localized?

Tags: facebook, url, localization, facebook-apps

The [Auth Dialog settings form](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#configure) for a Facebook app has fields which must contain URLs, including "Privacy Policy URL" and "Terms of Service URL".

Can these be localized? I know that the name of the field is already localized by Facebook, but is it possible to provide different URLs based on the user's locale?

I do not see the URLs appear as translatable strings in the Translation tool.

Thanks

Comment: No, you'd have to implement different languages on your side, and switch based on the user's locale

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit unfortunate. It is quite possible that the locale we will guess will not match the locale of the user's profile. I think I'll submit a feature request. An optional query parameter for the locale would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

You should also try to get user's geolocation or location by GeoIP and display different languages based in his region, and, if you can't access his geolocation, you display the standard policy in English.

Comment: Yes that's reasonable but especially for the terms of service we might be better off asking for the language first. If the user can't read the terms he might claim that the terms were not clearly displayed. Note that I did put in a feature request. Thanks for your input.